# Omit NA values while pasting two column values together in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `dd2`. I need to paste the values in `Left.Gene.Symbols` and `Right.Gene.Symbols` which I can do by simply using code below, but I would not want NAs pasted along if there is missing values. I want it to look like in the `combination` column as shown in `result`.

mycode

```
#to remove NAs
dd2[dd2 == 'NA'] <- NA
#pasting values together
result <- cbind(dd2,combination = paste(dd2[,"Left.Gene.Symbols"],dd2[,"Right.Gene.Symbols"],sep="*"))
```

data

```
dd2<- structure(c("AMLM12001KP", "AMLM12001KP", "AMLM12001KP", "AMLM12001KP", 
"AMLM12001KP", "AK2", "HFM1", "HFM1", "HFM1", "HFM1", NA, "PPT", 
NA, "GGT", NA), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("customer_sample_id", 
"Left.Gene.Symbols", "Right.Gene.Symbols")))
```

result

```
   customer_sample_id Left.Gene.Symbols Right.Gene.Symbols  combination
[1,] "AMLM12001KP"      "AK2"             NA                    AK2*
[2,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"           "PPT"                  HFM1*PPT
[3,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            NA                    HFM1*
[4,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"           "GGT"                  HFM1*GGT
[5,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            NA                    HFM1*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, temporarily replacing `NA` values with the empty character `""`.

```
cbind(
    dd2, 
    combination = paste(dd2[,2], replace(dd2[,3], is.na(dd2[,3]), ""), sep = "*")
)
#      customer_sample_id Left.Gene.Symbols Right.Gene.Symbols combinations
# [1,] "AMLM12001KP"      "AK2"             NA                 "AK2*"      
# [2,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            "PPT"              "HFM1*PPT"  
# [3,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            NA                 "HFM1*"     
# [4,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            "GGT"              "HFM1*GGT"  
# [5,] "AMLM12001KP"      "HFM1"            NA                 "HFM1*"
```

Of course substitute your column names for the column numbers above.  I didn't write them because they are too long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I have NAs in column 2 as well, can I just use replace (dd2[,2],is.na(dd2[,2]) ?

Comment: @MAPK - Yes, exactly.  But the call is `replace(dd2[,2],is.na(dd2[,2]) "")`.  You can do it for the entire matrix if you'd like.  `replace(dd2, is.na(dd2), "")`

Answer (score 3):

One way using `ifelse`

```
ifelse(is.na(dd2[,3]),paste0(dd2[,2],"*"),paste(dd2[,2],dd2[,3],sep="*"))

#[1] "AK2*"     "HFM1*PPT" "HFM1*"    "HFM1*GGT" "HFM1*"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `NAer` from `qdap` with `sprintf`

```
library(qdap)
sprintf('%s*%s', dd2[,2],NAer(dd2[,3],''))
#[1] "AK2*"     "HFM1*PPT" "HFM1*"    "HFM1*GGT" "HFM1*"
```